# Constraint a template parameter to only accept std::vector and std::list with C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

I am trying to write a program that sort only numbers in a std::vector or a std::list
for which I did 2 concepts:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept ValidContainer = requires(T a) {
    std::same_as<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type>>;
    std::same_as<T, std::list<typename T::value_type>>;
};
```

And:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Sortable = requires(T a) {
    ValidContainer<T> && std::same_as<typename T::value_type, int>;
    ValidContainer<T> && std::same_as<typename T::value_type, float>;
};
```

And the signature of the function that sorts them:

```cpp
void BubbleSort(Sortable auto& collection)
{
    // sort algorithm
}
```

The question that arises in my head is when I pass a `std::vector<std::string>` it does not show me a compilation error?

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test = { 32, 3, 6, 8, 2, 5, 0, 43, 67, 1 };
    std::vector<std::string> test2 = { "first", "second", "third" };

    BubbleSort(test);   // this is ok
    BubbleSort(test2);  // shouldn't this be a compile error?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why those two containers specifically? Why not a particular kind of range?

Comment: and if it would check value, `T` cannot be a `std::vector<U>` AND a `std::list<U>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept ValidContainer = requires(T a) {
    std::same_as<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type>>;
    std::same_as<T, std::list<typename T::value_type>>;
};
```

is checking to see if the *expression* `std::same_as<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type>>;` is valid, not that it also is `true`. Which is to say, it's basically just checking that `typename T::value_type` is a thing.

In that form, if you want to *require* something, you have to use `requires`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept ValidContainer = requires(T a) {
    requires std::same_as<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type>>;
    requires std::same_as<T, std::list<typename T::value_type>>;
};
```

Although now we're requiring that `T` is both a `vector` and a `list`, so that's never going to be true. So really we need:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept ValidContainer =
    std::same_as<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type>>
    || std::same_as<T, std::list<typename T::value_type>>;
```

Although even this isn't great because now we're rejecting `std::vector<T, MyAlloc>`.

---

This is separate from the question of why this is your constraint - why can you only sort `vector` and `list` ... but not like `deque` or `string` or `span` or ... ? Or why you're limiting to just `int` and `float`?

You can bubble sort any forward range that is orderable. Which I would express as:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::forward_range R>
    requires std::totally_ordered<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>
void BubbleSort(R& r);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I didn't know that the requires expressions were not evaluated (or implicitly converted to bool). 

Honestly, there is no particular reason beyond learning/practicing the new features of the language.

I knew about the existence of _ranges_ but didn't know that it could be used for cases like this. Again, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

`requires` expressions are `true` if the enclosed expressions are **well-formed**.  It does not matter if the expressions themselves evaluate to `true`.

(In fact, the expressions in a *requires-expression* are **never** evaluated)

You don't seem to be solving a problem that tests if an expression is well-formed.  Your concepts should look like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept ValidContainer =
    std::same_as<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type>> ||
    std::same_as<T, std::list<typename T::value_type>>;

template<typename T>
concept Sortable = 
    ( ValidContainer<T> && std::same_as<typename T::value_type, int> ) ||
    ( ValidContainer<T> && std::same_as<typename T::value_type, float> );
```

[See it in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7vGeWYWan)

Comment: This works for me! for some reason I was thinking that the _predicates list_ within the concept (or rather, within a require expression) was disjunctive,  or that aren't even evaluated, thank you so much! :)